# system with multiple network configurations (ethernet and wireless) and systemd-networkd cant reach target network-online

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a system that can connect with ethernet or wireless connection to the internet. I placed two network files into my networkd configuration folder.

While there is no wifi connection established `networkctl list` shows that `wlan0` is in the setup state `configuring`. Therefore my system can not reach the target `network-online.target`.

Is there a way to reach the target `network-online` while having two connections managed by `systemd-networkd` while one of them is optional?

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the `ExecStart` command `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` to:

`/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd-wait-online -i eth0 -i wlan0 --any`